# Can not get TensorFlow with XLA working

Tags: tensorflow

Has anyone successfully tried the example of mnist_softmax_xla in Step #3 of https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/jit I can not get it working. I am getting:

```
TF_XLA_FLAGS=--xla_generate_hlo_graph=.* python mnist_softmax_xla.py
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present
with 24 visible devices

I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:180] XLA service executing
computations on platform Host. Devices:

I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:187]   StreamExecutor device
(0): <undefined>, <undefined>
0.9198
```

I build TensorFlow r1.0 from source with XLA enabled. Does anyone have any ideas here? Thanks!

Comment: does this example work? https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/53052184e50cdfec35f0a127dd6df843

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks! It looks like your example is working. Do you know why the original example in [https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/jit](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/jit) does not work? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried those....if you are following the instructions on the official tutorial, and it's not working, then it's worth filing a bug

Comment: Yes, it looks like the example in the XLA doc only works with GPU, see comments here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7936

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681405/tensorflow-xla-not-producing-the-dot-file/51850509#51850509