# tensorflow XLA not producing the dot file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I am trying to follow the tutorial on XLA and JIT (https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit). According to https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit#step_3_run_with_xla, when I run the command

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit#step_3_run_with_xla
```

It should produce an output with the location to the XLA graph. However, my output does not include this info.

```
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
0.9172
```

Only the timeline file is generated.

Build: Tensor flow r1.3 with XLA JIT for CPU

Answer (score 0):

The key here is this part of the command:

```
TF_XLA_FLAGS=--xla_generate_hlo_graph=.*
```

The whole thing should be:

```
TF_XLA_FLAGS=--xla_generate_hlo_graph=.* python mnist_softmax_xla.py
```

With that, you should see a bunch of lines like:

```
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:1254] computation cluster_1[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v31 [GPU-ir-emit-prepare: after flatten-call-graph, pipeline end]: /tmp/hlo_graph_67.5dOpgX.dot
```

Note: I tested this on 1.4 not 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The full command should be

```
TF_XLA_FLAGS="--xla_hlo_graph_path=./tmp_dot --xla_generate_hlo_graph=.*" python mnist_softmax_xla.py
```

Make sure to have xla option when building from source. As well as requesting the device. ie

```
with tf.device("/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0"):
```

Also the example given uses tf.Variable, it should be replaced with tf.get_variable.

The full code will look like:

```
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at 
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# 
==============================================================================
"""Simple MNIST classifier example with JIT XLA and timelines.

"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

FLAGS = None


def main(_):
  # Import data
  with tf.device("/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0"):
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir)

    # Create the model
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    w = tf.get_variable("w",initializer=tf.zeros([784, 10]),use_resource=True)
    b = tf.get_variable("b",initializer=tf.zeros([10]),use_resource=True)
    y = tf.matmul(x, w) + b

    # Define loss and optimizer
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])

    # The raw formulation of cross-entropy,
    #
    #   tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(y)),
    #                                 reduction_indices=[1]))
    #
    # can be numerically unstable.
    #
    # So here we use tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy on the raw
    # logit outputs of 'y', and then average across the batch.
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=y_, logits=y)
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    jit_level = 0
    if FLAGS.xla:
      # Turns on XLA JIT compilation.
      jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1

    config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = jit_level
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
    # Train
    g = tf.Graph()
    print(dir(g))
    train_loops = 1000
    for i in range(train_loops):
      batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

      # Create a timeline for the last loop and export to json to view with
      # chrome://tracing/.
      if i == train_loops - 1:
        sess.run(train_step,
                 feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                            y_: batch_ys},
                 options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
                 run_metadata=run_metadata)
        trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
        with open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w') as trace_file:
          trace_file.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
      else:
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    # Test trained model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), y_)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(sess.run(accuracy,
                   feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                              y_: mnist.test.labels}))
    sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--data_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
      help='Directory for storing input data')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--xla', type=bool, default=True, help='Turn xla via JIT on')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```